# CQRS + ES shall we persist commands and queries?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

Tipically commands are used by handlers to modify aggregates state and emit events which get persisted to event store.

But depending on business logic today we might have some events emitted and some not tomorrow... **I wonder if this means that commands shall be persisted as well? Whats your experience with this?**

Also queries might be persisted for some analysis purposes imho...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a good question. Key thing to remember is that an event in an event sourced system represents something that has happened. Just because you change the logic in the future doesn't change the fact the event has already happened. How you deal with these events that have been deprecated is something you need to think about.

There are a number of routes you can take. One possibility is to create an upgrader for the event. Rather than handle the event, you run it through an upgrade process which effectively transforms it into the next version. Another route is to do the upgrade work within the model. You may even find that you can ignore it altogether in your new system.

Whatever you decide to do the most important thing to think about is the event stream as a whole. Ensure the changes you make don't prevent you from being able to re-run your events. Don't bust your event stream!

I've got a more in depth response to this in a post I wrote. You can find it here: [How to Upgrade CQRS Events Without Busting Your Event Stream](http://danielwhittaker.me/2015/02/02/upgrade-cqrs-events-without-busting/)

Hope you find it helpful.

Regarding your other points about storing queries and commands. You can do both, however, you need to be careful with them for different reasons.

Unless your entire system is based on CQRS and ES, re-running commands could fail because other systems are not in sync. This is not such a problem with the event stream. You should also be sure you handle sensitive information in commands. They may for example contain unencrypted info with the expectation of it being encrypted within the domain.

Regarding queries: One of the driving factors of CQRS is the ratio of reads to writes in the average line of business system. If you record queries you may hurt performance and will probably have a significantly higher requirement for storage space to handle the growth of data.

I found it useful to log both commands and queries, rather than just store them. This way I can a history of what gets run most often, duration and success. All useful health stats to monitor.

Anyway, hope thats helpful.

Comment: Maybe i'm misunderstanding things (i'm new in this theme) but i think you address a different issue, its event versioning when my events evolve over time, and i perfectly understand concept of upgrading old versions and getting rid of this problem. In various different presentations people warn about command and event souricng confusion... so basically when user does something we have a COMMAND (or EVENT?)

Comment: I think i shall treat them as events for example CreateOrder (Command) will be for me something like OrderCreationInitiated (event) before it goes into business logic or any event handler so that i record the initial source of modifications... not the result of modification...

Comment: as far as i understand all events can be of two categories, 1. initiated from outside of the system (by user for example) and 2. emited by business logic (those can change in future implementations) thus recording only 2 will not be reliable journal...

Comment: the point is if business logic changes and some event is no more emitted (type 2) then event stream kind of changes... thus i might need to mark type1 and type 2 evnets... is this correct?

Comment: The easy way to think about commands and events is this: A command is an action. Something that changes state - irrespective of where or who initiates it. An event is something that represents a state change. Notice that is a state change not the resultant state. Think of your event stream as append only. You can never go back and change an event. If you have a bug which created 'wrong' events then you issue compensating events rather than delete or edit old events. Again, if your system no longer issues a particular event you don't go back and change the event stream.